# Remove Email Domain from Name

Tags: python, pandas, text, data-cleaning

I have dataframe contain name column, but sometimes user fill it with an email address.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'],
                   'name': ['Andy','Ben@gmail.com','Charlie3@ymail.com','Dean','Edgar@icloud.com','Frank','Gabriel@yahoo.com']})
```

I want to remove the email domain so the reult will be just name or email username

```
id   name   
1    Andy       
2    Ben
3    Charlie
4    Dean
5    Edgar
6    Frank
7    Gabriel
```

I tried to use this funcion

```
def remove(name):
  name = re.sub(r'(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)|(\d+)',' ',name)
  return name

df['name'] = df['name'].apply(remove)
```

but there is still com in the result.

Comment: Try this `\d*@.*`.

Comment: Ok, I try df[['name']] = df[['name']].apply(lambda x:x.str.replace('\d*@.*.','')) and it's work. Thank you